# Symfony3 - force HTTPS except for certain routes

Tags: php, symfony, php-7

http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html#forcing-a-channel-http-https suggests to use `access_control` along `requires_channel: https` - this works great in general however I'm not able to find the solution which doesn't involve hacks (hardcoded patterns etc.).

I need to force HTTPS for all requests except for 1x certain route which requires HTTP. I can not use `path` because:

1. routes are translatable and therefore can change
2. there are other routes that also matches the pattern but have different route name.

Is there a way to tell Symfony to force HTTPS for everything except certain route or routes by name?

We are using annotations to load routes from `"@AppBundle/Controller/"` which also holds route which should use HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Comment: If you can't grab your route then you can't specify it... don't define everything as translated parts... and use a static part in your routes.

Comment: You say "routes are translatable" does that mean you already have a custom RouteLoader? If yes, you can define a "custom" option in your route, which tells the RouteLoader to specify if https is needed. But this might already be the sort of thing you call a hack ;-)

Comment: I can grab the route by name - that's the whole point. I'm using https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle